# How to create a shadow on a divider line in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a divider and I would like to create a bottom shadow on it, so basically I want a line with a bottom shadow.

how can I achieve that?

```
Divider(height:1)
```

Answer (score 6):

you don't need to use Divider at all. Container should be enough. Like this:

```
Container(
              height: 1.0,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.black,
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.orange,
                    spreadRadius: 5,
                    blurRadius: 5,
                    offset: Offset(0, 3), // changes position of shadow
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
```

EDIT:
Another option is to not use box shadow but linear gradient to simulate shadow only at bottom like this:

```
Container(
              height: 10,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border(
                  top: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    width: 1.0,
                  ),
                ),
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                  begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                  end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  colors: [
                    Colors.orange,
                    Colors.white,
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            )
```

Cheers

Comment: I need the center of the shadow to be the line and grow only to the bottom, this code puts shadow on up and down

Comment: You can simply modify the BoxShadow as you need. For example like this: BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    spreadRadius: 1,
                    blurRadius: 1,
                    offset: Offset(0, 4)
                  ),

Comment: fam this is moving the whole shadow to 4 pixels down from the bottom rather than drawing only on the bottom.

Comment: Thats how box shadow works. I edited my answer with another solution using gradient only at bottom. Pls check if that is what you need

Comment: that looked quite better but since there is a scrollView under it, it looks bad when you start scrolling as it is a box.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your divider into a container and apply shadow to your container like this.

```
    Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                spreadRadius: 2,
                blurRadius: 7,
                offset: Offset(0, 6), // changes position of shadow
              ),
            ],
          ),
          child: Divider(
            height: 1,
            indent: 15,
            endIndent: 15,
            thickness: 1,
            color: Colors.blue,
          ),
        ),
```

Change properties according to your preference.

Comment: I need the center of the shadow to be the line and grow only to the bottom, this code puts shadow on up and down of the y-axis